# Make multiline textbox remember text input (auto complete)

Tags: asp.net, autocomplete, textbox, textarea, multiline

A normal asp.net textbox will remember your old inputs - if you type something into a textbox and leave the page then come back, and type the same thing. The textbox will "auto complete" what you are typing by suggesting what you typed the last time.

I can see that if you set the Textmode property to "multiline" the textbox then loses it's auto complete. Like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_Description"  TextMode="MultiLine" MaxLength="500"   runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

How do I add this funcitonality to my multiline asp Textbox or a TextArea? (multiline textboxes are rendered as textareas).

I am open to both asp.net specific solutions and javascript/jquery solutions.

Comment: I do not want to predefine what the Textbox should suggest as auto completion. It should only be strings that the textbox remembers from the last time the user visited the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve what was in the multiline textbox and then cache it and on a postback use the cache to output what was used before.

```
// Get everything in the multiline text box and cache it
Cache["multilineValues"] = TextBox_Description.Text;

// Output what was written again through cache etc when the page loads after a postback. 
//You would most likely put this in the Page_Load method.
if(IsPostBack)
{
    if(Cache["multilineValues"] != null)
    {
      //Use what was written before
      TextBox_Description.Text = (string)Cache["multilineValues"];
    }
}
```